# Why is my JS logic appearing on index (using ejs/express)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

im having an issue understanding why my JS is appearing on my layout. Im currently following along with a tutorial on sitepoint creating forms with in express and when i render the layout.ejs + index.ejs with contact as a partial, the logic on partial is appearing on the page as text.

here is the code:

```
<div class="form-header">
<% if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) { %>
<h2>Send us a message aa</h2>
<% } else { %>
<h2 class="errors-heading">Oops, please correct the following:</h2>
<ul class="errors-list">
    <% Object.values(errors).forEach(error => { %>
    <li><%= error.msg %></li>
    <% }) %>
</ul>
<% } %>
</div>

<form method="post" action="/contact" novalidate>
    <div class="form-field <%= errors.message ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' 
%>">
        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea class="input" id="message" name="message" rows="4" 
autofocus><%= data.message %></textarea>
        <% if (errors.message) { %>
        <div class="error"><%= errors.message.msg %></div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field <%= errors.email ? 'form-field-invalid' : '' %>">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input class="input" id="email" name="email" type="email" value="<%= 
data.email %>" />
        <% if (errors.email) { %>
        <div class="error"><%= errors.email.msg %></div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you added View Engine app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); in server.js file

Comment: @yogeshrathod yes i have

Comment: i have solved this issue, it was a simple artifact file causing the rendering issue. Please close